# Difference between zk-rollups and nocust-zkp

Tags: scalability, zksnark, rollups, zksync

What is the fundamental difference between ZK-Rollup and Nocust-ZKP? Does the data availability problem still persist in Nocust-ZKP? After going through zk-sync, I felt it might be fundamentally similar to Nocust-ZKP.